# Full Copy Sandboxes - Storage Capacity

Tags: sandbox

As per Salesforce,

Full copy sandboxes have the same storage limit as your production organization.

I want to know what is the "storage limit" exactly, just like for Config-Only sandbox, it is 500 MB, for developer sandbox, it is 10 MB. What is it for Full-Copy Sandbox?

Also, I have heard that each record's storage size is 2 KB. Please confirm if this is correct and also let me know accordingly, how many maximum records can exist in a Full-Copy / Production environment.

Comment: I believe there is a per use data and file storage limit, depending on the Edition(20MB/User for EE and 120MB /User for UE).  http://www.sfdcstatic.com/uk/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare_UK.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Most records take up 2KB, there are some [exceptions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193871) (KB: 000193871):

- Person Accounts - 4KB
- Campaigns - 8KB
- Campaign Members – 1KB
- Articles - 4KB
- Email Message - This is dependent upon the content of the messages, a 100kb email message takes 100kb of data storage space.  Text only emails will take less than HTML due to only being the body text and not the html code and text version as well.

Your full sandbox will be able to store the same amount of records as your production one.

Comment: Please note that Person Accounts is not a line item; there is just an Account and Contact for each one, hence the 4KB.

Answer (score 2):

As you quoted, the full copy sandbox has the same storage limit as your production org. This limit varies on an org-by-org basis so we can't tell you definitively how much you have. You can check this on the Setup page, though by going to `Setup | Administer | Data Management | Storage Usage`. From there you will see the number of each record that exists and how much storage that object is consuming. Generally speaking, yes, each record takes up 2KB.

For instance, in my org I see 75,685 Leads, consuming 147.8MB, which works out to 2KB each.

Comment: But you'll have least 1GB, the minimum for any Enterprise Edition org. We know that much. The upper limit is directly related to license counts plus any additional storage purchased separately.